# C# - Paste multiline cells to excel from a string

Tags: c#, excel

I was trying copying a string to an excel line using "\r" to separate the cells. I want only 2 cells to be multiline but using "\n" will switch the text over to the next line in the spreadsheet instead of making a new line in the cell. (The program automaticly copies the text to the Clipboard)

Is there any way to achieve this?

For example if you have a string:

```
    string s = "cell1 \t cell2 \t cell3 \n stillcell3 \t cell4";
```

It will result in (cell(contents)):
A1(cell1) A2(cell2) A3(cell3 *newline* stillcell3) A4(cell4)

I hope it made sense and it would be great if you could help me!

**Solution:**
Make sure you have enclosed the multiline section in `\"\"`.

Comment: What are you using to communicate with Excel? Interop/COM Objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "cell1\tcell2\t\"cell3\nstillcell3\"\tcell4\r\n";
Clipboard.SetText(s);
```

Now go to Excel and Paste

```
(Control + V)
```

Comment: +1 just because I don't think that anonymous -1 is good for anything. But this answer is not +1 worthy at all. First of all, you don't even know how the OP is connecting to Excel and second you cannot advise to  paste manually; in principle, everything has to be done via code. Also without setting the Wrap Text property to true in the given cell, you would never get multi-line.

Comment: Thank you, If very very bad answer tell me and I will delete it. The user did not specify how it communicates, so I assumed some basic solution.

Comment: Look at what others are telling you: second downvote in a not-too-popular question. I have explained already what I see wrong here. First thing to do before answering is knowing the problem; you don't even know the problem. And, as said, your solution does not deliver an accurate result in virtually any scenario: you are not mentioning wrapping, you rely on the user-intervention (what is almost forbidden)... I honestly don't see the point of this answer, but is completely up to you.

Comment: I used the Clipboard in my program. The only thing I was wondering about is if there is a possibility to wrap all the text in only one excel-line and create multiline cells when there are breaks. Maybe there is, maybe not. I was just wondering - EDIT: I actually meant /t instead of /r

Comment: This is what that sample string that I answered does. Test the sample string I provided above. Notice that for line break inside a cell you need to enclose in Quotes like "line1\nline2"

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice it. You're my hero :P

Comment: Useful question, useful answer; thanks Tony